# I need help on a summing pattern

Tags: python, design-patterns, lambda, sum

> sum S(t):
>   S(1) = 1
>   S(2) = 4 + 1 + 4
>   S(3) = 9 + 4 + 1 + 4 + 9
>   S(4) = 16 + 9 + 4 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16
>   S(5) = 25 + 16 + 9 + 4 + 1 + 4 + 9 + 16 + 25

```
def combine(f, op ,n):
    result = f(0)
    for i in range(n):
        result = op(result, f(i))
    return result


def sum(t):
    f = lambda x: 2*(x**2)
    op = lambda x,y: x+y
    n = t+1
    return combine(f, op, n)
```

However, I am **not** allowed to change the definition of `combine(f, op ,n)`.

Is there a way to redefine `sum(t)` to remove the extra 1 so that my code is correct?

correct answers are: `1,9,27,59,109`

my code gives: `2,10,28,60,110`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`combine` uses `range(n)` so always starts counting at 0; you cannot avoid adding 1 to `t` to get the desired results. You do need to special-case the `0` and `1` arguments to `f`:

```
def sum(t):
    f = lambda x: 2 * (x**2) if x > 1 else x
    op = lambda x, y: x + y
    return combine(f, op, t + 1)
```

Now `f(0)` and `f(1)` return `0` and `1` respectively, producing the expected output:

```
>>> for i in range(1, 6):
...     print 'sum({}) => {}'.format(i, sum(i))
... 
sum(1) => 1
sum(2) => 9
sum(3) => 27
sum(4) => 59
sum(5) => 109
```